# How to regenerate Refresh Token and Access Token on Resource Request?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, middleware, refresh-token

I am trying implementing JWT Tokens(Access tokens and Refresh tokens), but I come to an issue on requesting a protected resource with an expired access token, while the refresh token is still valid.

I know that I should not use refresh tokens to request resources, refresh tokens should be used against authorization validators to revalidate/regenerate access tokens.

In my app, the User can log in by POST request with a valid credential to get Access token(exp. in 1min) and Refresh token(exp. in 10min.). Say now User making a request 30 sec later of login and sends both tokens, then tokens get checked and resource comes back. If now user makes a request after 2min and sends tokens, his access token is Invalid, in this scenario how can I proceed with the request and revalidate tokens.

**I can think of middleware to validate and provide tokens and send that with the response, but is this the right approach?**
**Then I need to handle and restore tokens on the client-side for every response. Don't I?**

Also, I do not want to prompt users to re-login. I am using Node and Express for Server and React on Client.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your steps:

1. Try to login
2. Receive 401 from server when token is invalid
3. Request a new access token by making a new refresh request.
4. Set the new access token and refresh token
5. Retry original request

This has to be done on the client side because it is the audience that gets validated for authorization.

Usually we don't set the access token to expire every minute because the described process would add too much latency to the process.

Edit from @MComment:

5 min for access tokens and 30 min up to a few hours is what is generally recommended for respectively access and refresh tokens. Usually Authorization Servers offer "rolling refresh" - refresh token's expiration is renewed whenever you use it. This way a user stays logged in as long as they are actively using the website

Comment: 5 min for access tokens and 30 min up to a few hours is what is generally recommended for respectively access and refresh tokens. Usually Authorization Servers offer "rolling refresh" - refresh token's expiration is renewed whenever you use it. This way a user stays logged in as long as they are actively using the website.

Answer (score -1):

You can update expired date of access token in every request, no need to regenerate token.
I think session time you set is not normal and recommended.
If you dont want user must re-login, make a forever refresh token, create a function in reactjs for re-generate access token by refresh token if it expired.
Revoke refresh token only when u want to logout from this client.